# How to install GraphViz and use it on Kodingen?

Tags: installation, graphviz

I would like to use GraphViz to generate graph pictures and view them on web.  GraphViz work fine on my computer but how can I use it on a linux server?

At the moment, I use Kodingen.com to run my site.  Is it possible to use GraphViz on the web and generate pictures from .dot files?  What is the procedure to install it? And obviously to use it?

For exemple on my computer (windows) I use:

```
dot.exe -Tpng "input.dot" -o "output.png"
```

Comment: You'll need to add what kind of server you're installing to e.g. Windows, Linux

Comment: @RichardNienaber : I checked and it's Linux.

Comment: You might just ask your hosting provider to install it.

Comment: this graphviz doesn't seem to be a php/python component, even if we installed it to the server you'd need shell access to be able to use it, or am i missing something? because if so, kodingen doesn't provide shell access to your accounts yet.

Comment: @Devrim Thank you for your response. It's clear ! I think I will try to search for another graph module... in python I prefer.   But the question is the same, how to install a python package on kodingen to use it???

Comment: @devrim that's right, it's a separate program (interpreter) that you would have to spawn as a subprocess.  I'm not familiar with kodingen, so I don't know their policies. Perhaps OP should use a different service provider instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make this question answered, I link [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134064/how-to-install-and-use-python-packages-on-kodingen/5134295#5134295) from another question I ask.

> Devrim said:
>
> ... kodingen provides shared hosting account that doesn't enable anyone to install anything. same applies to ruby gems. but we will make this possible very soon.
>
> just to reiterate, kodingen is able to run python/perl/php scripts, just not external/custom libraries until we give you your own servers...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you would do this like any other package on Kodingen. Using the toolbar on the left:

1. Click on App Store
2. Scroll to the bottom of the list and click Search for applications
3. Type in graphviz and click List applications

However when I tried to install it, it failed. This seems to be because the [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/graphviz) doesn't have a download page for it.

Depending on your flavour of Linux (Ubuntu, RedHat), you should be able to install it via the [package manager](http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-swinstall.html#quick_reference). So for instance, on Ubuntu/Debian, you should be able to enter `sudo apt-get install graphviz` from the shell and have it be installed.

Comment: After your first question, when I looked for the server platform, I tried to install it via the App Store and it failed indeed.  But...  Suppose I install GraphViz (maybe asking at Ohlow), how I use it ?  On my computer, I use it in command line (`dot.exe -Tpng "input.dot" -o "output.png"`). How to use it on a server ? (we suppose GraphViz is installed...)