# How to install and use python packages on Kodingen?

Tags: python, installation, package

I use [Kodingen.com](http://kodingen.com) to test python scripts.  I would like to install new python packages on Kodingen.  I know I can use the 1-Click installation of the App-Store to install new packages from [ohloh.net](http://ohloh.net).  When I install a package, it create a new directory in httpdocs folder.  And then?  How to setup the python package to use import in my scripts?  Is it possible for a user to do it?

I'm looking for the complete procedure.  As example, we can use PIL (Python Imaging Library). How to install it?

For information, Kodingen use a linux server.
I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124218/how-to-install-graphviz-and-use-it-on-a-linux-web-server) but this one is a more general question about the python packages install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey thammas, we are working on kodingen v1.0 with which you will be able to use your own server connected to your account. then you can install anything and use it freely.

but now, kodingen provides shared hosting account that doesn't enable anyone to install anything. same applies to ruby gems. but we will make this possible very soon.

just to reiterate, kodingen is able to run python/perl/php scripts, just not external/custom libraries until we give you your own servers. hope it clarifies.

Comment: Thanks Devrim for your clarification.  I will wait !